# How do you round quotients when dividing in nasm?

Tags: assembly, decimal, nasm, divide

im not sure if m using the wrong data types or the wrong instruction or what but div,idiv,fdiv all seem to give me a 0 for the quotient. And i want to get some decimal number rounded to a couple decimal places. i think im using the correct registers for the division too.

```
mov ebp, 3          ;ebp = 3(constant) 
mov eax, edx            ;eax = edx(sum from previous calculation)
mov ecx,3           ;load upper half of dividend with zero
div ecx             ;divide double register ecx eax by 3

push eax
push msg6
call _printf
add esp, 8
```

i changed the format in the printf so it displays in decimal format but there are still no numbers being divided it seems like?

Comment: also im using nasm with mingw on a windows machine if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov ebp, 3          ;ebp = 3(constant)
mov eax, edx        ;eax = edx(sum from previous calculation)
mov ecx,3           ;load upper half of dividend with zero
div ecx             ;divide double register ecx eax by 3
```

It seems like your doing the division the wrong way! The code does not what the comments suggest.
If EDX holds the sum from the previous calculation then you should move it into EAX but also clear EDX to prepare for the upcoming division.
This is how the correct code looks:

```
mov ebp, 3          ;ebp = 3(constant)
mov eax, edx        ;eax = edx(sum from previous calculation)
mov edx, 0          ;load upper half of dividend with zero
div ebp             ;divide edx:eax by 3
```

To work with 2 decimal places you can multiply by 100 prior to doing the division and then later insert a decimal point character before the last 2 characters of the result displayed as text.

Answer (score 0):

`div` performs (unsigned) integer division. it means that you get an integral quotient and a remainder less than the divisor.

if you don't want to use floats, you could multiply the remainder by 10^n and divide again (n would be the number of decimals you want). this new quotient will be an integer between 0 and 10^n, but you can use it as representing the n digits after the decimal dot.

to add rounding you should add 1 to this result if the remainder is greater or equal than divisor/2.

EDIT

this is (more or less) what you would do to get the decimals by hand.
for example to get `18/7` with two decimals the first division produces quotient=`2`, remainder=`4`.

next, if you multiply the remainder by 100 and divide again

```
4*100/7 -> quotient=57, remainder=1
```

so the number would be 2.57 (truncating). to consider rounding you should see if the following digit would be less than 5 or not. That would be the case if the last remainder was less than divisor/2. Consider that adding 1 to the number that represents the decimal part could propagate to the integer part (for example calculating 999/1000 with two decimals).

Comment: this way doesnt get it in the decimal form though does it? and if i wanted to use floats would i need to redo the entire code so that the data matches with float? googling how to implement floating division seems complicated. alot of conversions n such just to get a decimal number

Comment: @user2288023 it should give you the first n digits after the dot as an integer.